# Conga Template Tabbing Issue

Tags: salesforce1-app, conga-composer

I have a merge field template created in Microsoft Word, all the merge fields and signature tags populate correctly however when we send the document to a client for signature the tabbing goes out of order on some rows of the table (from right-left)
Whereas some of the rows tab properly (left to right) for the user to input the data. Not sure what causes the sequence but I've tried recreating the template and everything, recently i found how to show non printable character for formatting and not certain if some of those characters are causing this. Any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: I am no guru on Conga, but I am thinking, this could be the effect of screen resolution differences. As you are sharing just Word document, you should do some research in that perspective, rather than trying to figure it out in Salesforce. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Hi Arnold, thanks for your response, I only posted in the Salesforce thread as the Conga Composer is used in union with that platform, however i think we are both on the right track thinking its a Microsoft Word issue as opposed to Salesforce.